# Java method for checking whether an element of an array exists

Tags: java, function, class, for-loop, oop

I have two classes called Ticket and Register. Register is a class that takes in a ticket array. A ticket contains a time and a string with its Ticket ID. One of the methods in my Register Class is called contains() and it returns a Boolean. It checks whether the register contains a ticket with that ID. My problem is that it only shows true for the first ticket element and false for all the others even if it contains the ticket, therefore I believe the problem is with my contains() function. I am very knew to Java so if someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code for Register and my driver code.

```
/
// This is class called Register that has the methods:"add()","contains()","retrieve()" and the constructor "Register()"

public class Register{ 

public Ticket[] tickets; 
public int numTickets; 

public Register(){ 
tickets = new Ticket[100]; 
numTickets = 0; 

}

public void add(Ticket ticket){ //add ticket method. Takes a ticket as a parameter and adds it to the array

tickets[numTickets] = ticket;
numTickets = numTickets+1; // incramenting array

}


public boolean contains(String ticketID){ //contains method. Takes a string from the ticket using the ID() method and uses as a parameter.

boolean b = false; 

for (int i = 0;i<100;i++){ 

if (ticketID.equals(tickets[i].ID())){ // checks to see if ticket ID is in the array
b = true; // return value is true if found
break;
}
break; 
}
return b; // returns true of false
}

public Ticket retrieve(String ticketID){ // returns the ticket with the specified ID

int j = 0; // initializing return value
for (int i = 0;i<100;i++){ 

if (ticketID.equals(tickets[i].ID())){ 

j = i; 
break;     
}

}

return tickets[j]; // returns ticket
}


}
```

Here is my driver code

```
public static void main(String[] args){


Register r = new Register();
Ticket t;
t = new Ticket(new Time("13:00"), "00001");
String ID_One = t.ID();
r.add(t);

t = new Ticket(new Time("13:18"), "00002");
String ID_Two = t.ID();
r.add(t);
System.out.println(r.contains(ID_One));
System.out.println(r.contains("00002"));
System.out.println(r.retrieve(ID_Two).toString());
```

Output is:

```
true
false // this should be true
Ticket[id=00002, time=13:18:00]
```

Comment: First, you should indent your code properly. Indentation helps yourself and others read your code. Second, you have two `break` statements. The first one probably belongs there, and the second one is unconditionally executed, so the loop is always exited after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the second `break`, which always exits the `for` loop on the first iteration, so only the first element of the array is ever compared.

You could simplify your code to 1 line:

```
public boolean contains(String ticketID) {
    return Arrays.stream(tickets).map(Ticket::ID).anyMatch(ticketID::equals);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `break` statement outside your `if` condition, so it will only check the first element then break the loop. You can see this immediately with better formatting.

```
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++){ 
  if (ticketID.equals(tickets[i].ID())){ // checks to see if ticket ID is in the array
    b = true; // return value is true if found
    break;
  }
  break; 
}
```

Remove the second `break` to fix this so you only break when your `if` condition is true.

For personal advise, you might want to consider using a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) structure if you have a unique ID for each ticket. This can reduce your search time considerably.

```
int numTickets = 0;
Map<String, Ticket> ticketMap = new HashMap<>();

public void add(Ticket ticket) {
  numTickets++;
  ticketMap.put(ticket.ID(), ticket);
}

public boolean contains(String ticketId) {
  return ticketMap.containsKey(ticketId);
}

public Ticket retrieve(String ticketId) {
  return ticketMap.get(ticketId);
}
```